# “Suggestion card” vs. “comment card”: Which is more common?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am about to launch a new restaurant in my country. I also want to have a small paper of survey to collect data from the customers as well to help me understand my users better. The question types in this little survey can vary such as multiple choice, rating, or even comment box. And it contains no more than ten questions to keep it short.

I am not sure how to name it. Should it be *suggestion card* or *comment card*? Or just call it a *survey* (but I think *survey* should be something with more detail)

Answer (score 1):

You should most certainly not use the word **survey** since it amounts to an inspection or examination of some kind, and is usually carried out simultaneously amongst multiple, or a group of participants.

The word you're looking for is **feedback**. You are *requesting* your potential customers for an assessment or an evaluation of your services (and food). Better yet, you could group the both of them together into a **feedback and suggestions card** if you're still confused.

Comment: A **feedback** form to compile in a *restaurant*, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, a "suggestion" form sounds more like what an employee would fill out to suggest a process improvement or something. A "comment" card sounds more like what a customer might fill out, especially if there's a prominent free-form field where they can write whatever they want to tell you. I would disagree with stuxnetting about the use of "survey": it may have a technical meaning but it's widely used to mean "getting customer feedback".

A "Customer Feedback Card" might be appropriate. Ten questions sounds like too much work to me as a restaurant patron, and I wouldn't fill it out. Make it four questions, with a fifth field to write whatever I want to tell you and call it a customer feedback card.